# Fatal error in WordPress, "Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted"

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a WordPress beginner and I have only rudimentary knowledge about CSS and HTML. I have built a WordPress blog in the last days, and it was working well. But since two days I couldn't login and couldn't open the page (but I haven't touch the page since about one week, I don't know what happened). This is what was shown:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 50331648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes) in /home/u0087038969/public_html/wp-admin/includes/deprecated.php on line 533

I suggested that one of the installed plugins caused this trouble. That's why I changed the name of the plugin file via FileZilla, so that I get access to WordPress again. Then I tried to reactivate the plugins gradually to find the trouble-maker. Still it's not really working. What can I do to go about solving the problem?

p.s. I used the following wp plugins: mail poet, all in one seo and contact form 7.

Comment: Did you change the name of the file after deactivating the plugin or while it was active?

Comment: I couldn't deactivate the plugin before because I had no access to the backend.

Comment: Now I have access to the backend, but I can't activate the plugins or adjust the layout of the theme anymore.

Comment: Perhaps you should rename the file to it's original name, login to the admin section and then try to deactivate the plugin plus if you want to you can change the file name after deactivating, but don't think it would be needed.

Comment: That's what I did. I renamed the file, logged in and tried to open the plugin area in the backend. That's not possible. I get the error message.

Comment: Please list in your question all of your plugins, or at least the one(s) you believe are causing the trouble. Are the problematic plugins in popular usage, according to the WP site? Some are written so badly they should not be used - a common problem with code from the WP community.

Comment: Like @halfer said please provide the name of the plugin you are having issues with.

Comment: I used mail poet, all in one seo and contact form 7.

Comment: ^ Please add that detail **in your question** as requested - important detail is often missed in comments. The 'edit' button is just under the tag row above.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your installation is requiring more memory than you have available for your site. If you are using a shared hosting environment, you might be at a loss in increasing your memory allotment.

Try updating your `wp-config` file:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256MB');
```

If you can change your PHP.ini file you can adjust this:

```
php_value memory_limit 256MB
```

Your host seems to have this set incredibly low if it's giving you a memory error at 50MB.

Comment: Yes, my host gave me only 48 MB. Obviously it is too low. Where do I find the php.ini file?

Comment: This will probably fix things, but it's worth noting that 256M for a web process is rather on the high side. I appreciate some WP plugins are not written well, and so are excessively memory hungry, but that should be something that a developer aims to fix, rather than just throwing more server resource at it. Personally I'd be more comfortable with 128M.

Comment: I can't believe it! Now I get the following error message after trying to update the wp-config file: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/u0087038969/public_html/wp-config.php on line 31

Comment: I was able to fix at least this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to fix it with playing WP_MEMORY_LIMIT. But it did not help me. Fixed by PHP upgrade from 7.0 to 7.2